# The reason 'subprocess.run' is better than 'os.system' for beginner

Tags: python, os.system

I read many answers on this topic.

It seems that they try to explain it with much more difficult illustrations or just saying it's deprecated consulting official documentation.

`os.system` is handy for beginner.

Could the reason be explained in an easy example o a metaphor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example of many is that `subprocess.run()` can capture the output, while `os.system()` only captures the return code.

`subprocess.run()` is simply way more flexible. It can do everything that `os.system()` can but also way more. If you KNOW that you never will use any of the benefits in `subprocess.run()`, then by all means, use `os.system()`, but most people would say that it's a bit of a waste of time to learn two different tools for the same thing.

`os.system()` is pretty much a copy of `system()` in C.